# VBA Excel: Userform Textbox to show value of cell referenced in formula

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an excel workbook with two worksheets, used by my executives & their admin assistants to co-ordinate workflow tasks.

Data added to Sheet 1 (Support Staff Workflow) is 'copied' using a simple in-cell formula on Sheet 2 (Broker Workflow) - i.e cell B9 formula is *='Support Staff Workflow'!B9*

Columns A:F are identical in both sheets and these columns are protected in Sheet 2 so that they're only able to be edited via Sheet 1

When a broker selects a cell in Column B (Client Name) of Sheet 2, a command button becomes visible so they can call a userform and select the administration tasks they want support staff to complete for that client.

My userform has 2 textboxes (Client Name & Policy Number) and various Y/N option boxes for each task. 
The command button will find the matching Client Name (Column B) and Policy Number (Column E) on sheet 1 and enter a value for the tasks required for that transaction.

To ensure we can match the client name & policy number on Sheet 1, I want to auto-fill these textboxes to the value of the cell that the broker selected [to call the userform]. The problem I'm having is getting my VBA code to fetch the text in Sheet 1 instead of the formula that's in the selected cell on Sheet 2 (which is resulting in a blank textbox).

I've tried searching online for a solution but haven't been able to find anything to assist.

Any help that you could provide with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The code on my userform (that's trying to fill these textboxes with values from Sheet 2) is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   With Me
       .TxtClient.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row,"B").Value 
       .TxtPolNum.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row,"E").Value
   End With
End Sub
```

When I run the form, the textboxes appear blank. I presume because the ActiveCell contains a formula not an actual value/text?

Comment: I must confess I did not understand too much about your problem... Can you confirm that the selected cell does show a value? Even if it is the result of a formula... If yes, `ActiveCell.Value` will return what you can see when select it. Even if what you can see is the result of a formula. If not, please focusing on the environment description, referring to the cell where from the data must be extracted... You have to post here your code. Maybe the way of finding the cell is wrong. Otherwise, I am afraid, we cannot help you...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru
Thanks for the message. I tried to upload a screenshot of the two sheets but I'm too new to this site and it won't let me. I've edited the question with some of the code and am hoping that it clarifies it for you?
The selected cell on Sheet 2 does show the value but when it's selected, the formula bar displays only the actual formula not the text value that was returned from Sheet 1

Comment: Are you sure that `ActiveCell` is in the worksheet you need to be? Try inserting of the next code line in your form Initialize event: `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address(external:=True)`. What does it show in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G in Visual Basic Editor)?

Comment: You want to target the cells in the Sheet1 but your Activesheet is Sheet2. Have you tried to write something like .TxtClient.Value = Sheet1.Cells(Activecell.Row, "B").Value ?